# object showing unexpected results

Tags: javascript

i wrote this code

```
var myObj={
    a:'kaka',
    b:'beck'
};


var finalname=myObj[b]);
console.log(finalname);
```

The code shows nothing in console.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: By nothing do you mean "NOTHING" or some error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you getting error in first place while calling:

```
var finalname=myObj[b]);
```

It should be:

```
var finalname=myObj["b"];
```

Without an "**)**" and inside quotes **""**

OR

```
var finalname=myObj.b;
```

Answer (score 4):

use `myObj.b` instead of `myObj["b"]`

```
var myObj = {
   a: 'kaka',
   b: 'beck'
};


var finalName = myObj.b;
console.log(finalName);
```

If you intend to use square bracket notation, then the key should be a string.

```
var myObj = {
       'a': 'kaka',
       'b': 'beck'
    };


    var finalName = myObj['b'];
    console.log(finalName);
```

Comment: @But how to use the square bracket notation?

Comment: var myObj={
    a:'kaka',
    b:'beck'
};


var finalname=myObj['b'];
console.log(finalname);

you can directly  do this.

Answer (score 1):

b need to be a string or a variable

```
var myObj={
    a:'kaka',
    b:'beck'
};


var finalname=myObj['b'];
console.log(finalname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myObject = {...};

myObject.attr; // try to get an attribute named as attr,

myObject["attr"]; // try to get an attribute named as attr,

myObject[attr]; // try to get an attribute named as the value of attr.

/*

conclusion:
any thing appeared in square bracket is considered as an expression,
the owner object try to find  the attribute named as the expression's value.
otherwise, square bracket is more powerfull:
  
  myObject["a-b"]
  myObject["1"]
  myObject["a b"]
  ...
  myObject["anything"]
  
  while:
  
  myObject.a-b // the value of myObject's attribute a minus the value of b
  myObject.1 // grammatical mistake
  myObject.a b // grammatical mistake

*/
```